# Why does System.TypeInitializationException occur?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the WebClient Class in c#, and I need it for a method and an Event Listener, so I defined it in a class. When I try to run my program, System.TypeInitializationException occurs, and I do not know why. I have looked for solutions but cannot find one.

Here is my code (Edited):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static WebBrowser browser1 = new WebBrowser();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //some code
        browser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

    }
    static void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
        Main(null);
    }

}
```

When I comment out the WebBrowser variable and any code that needs it, the code works fine. Please help me, as I am new to C Sharp.

Comment: When your Debugger reports the Exception, have a look at the InnerException.

Comment: Is this the complete code? Methods cannot exist outside of a class or struct.

Comment: The DocumentCompleted handler is going to call back into your Main method and cause an infinite loop and probably crash your program.  Is that intended?

Comment: `WebBrowser != WebClient` the former is a full browser and needs WinForms, what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The error says

```
ThreadStateException: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be 
instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
```

Add the STAThread attribute above your main method

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
```